# Django: list_display is not callable

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a few models: ModelA, ModelB, ModelC each with identical attributes say x,y,z. I am trying to get them displayed in Django admin.
I have registered each as

```
@admin.register(ModelA)
class ModelAAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['x', 'y' , 'z']
```

However when I runserver, I get error which says

```
The value of list_display[0] refers to 'x' which is not callable, an attribute of modelA, or an attribute or method on 'database.modelA'
```

I am guessing this has got something to do with each model having identical names but I am not sure. How do I resolve this?

EDIT- the models are pretty basic with

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    x = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    y = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    z = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
```

Comment: mex_length is it a typo ?

Comment: yup. correcting it

Comment: @admin.register(ModelA):   also remove ':' here

Answer (score 2):

Set `list_display` to control which fields are displayed on the change list page of the admin.
Example:

```
list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name')
```

[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)

**Edit**
can you try this?

```
class ModelAAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = ModelA
    list_display = ['x', 'y' , 'z',] # important there is a comma after 'z',

admin.site.register(ModelA, ModalAAdmin)
```

Comment: That is what I am trying to do but it results in the error mentioned

Comment: @Bayko but in your code you write `list_display = ['x', 'y' , 'z']` like `list` but try `list_display = ('x', 'y', 'z')` like `tuple`

Comment: you have this `['x', 'y', 'z']` attributes in your model  ?

Comment: class modelA(models.Model): x = models.CharField(max_length = 30) y = models.CharField(max_length = 30) z = models.CharField(max_length = 30) . Pretty much a basic model

Comment: @Bayko edit your question, and add there the model with all attributes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171572/discussion-between-zimdero-and-bayko).

Answer (score 0):

list_display = ['x', 'y' , 'z']

Change to:

list_display = ['x', 'y' , 'z',]

Note: always put a "," after the last fields that you want to display